# SystemStackOverflowException When I try to calculate the precentage of field

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors

I'm trying to calculate the percentage on the textbox by using the next code:

```
t45.Text = (CDbl(Me.t43.Text) / CDbl(Me.t48.Text))
```

but I faced the next message:
System.StackOverflowException

what the problem???!

I tried to find what happened but I didn't find.

Comment: What's the values of t43 and t48 when the exception is thrown?

Comment: You should use [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) - it will point out some problems for you and suggest corrections. For example, it would tell you that you can't assign a Double (the result of the calculation) to a String (what the .Text property is).

Comment: Something is missing. `a = b / c` won't raise a StackOverflowException if b and c are simply values. But if `b = a`, then you have recursion and you could get that exception. Double supports Infinity, so even if you *think* you may have a mathematical overflow, (i.e. t48 = 0) your math should work and t45 will be ∞. Look elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe look at the exception.  It contains diagnostic information, including the stack trace.